# Perform an action clicking notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create notifications correctly, but as I can not perform an action when you click on the notification. I hope you can help me or give some clue.

Comment: please post some code and clearly state your error!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use `Notification.Builder` and `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the support library for building notifications.

Also why do use reuse the `Intent` which was caught by your `BroadcastReceiver`? It should refer to the actual activity which you want to launch by click.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
```

If you doesn't really want to launch some activity, you may start a `Service` or send a broadcast message instead. See [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Comment: i want to launch a web, how i can do this??

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));`
Then pass it to
`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Text",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("somekey", "someextra");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title", "Message", pIntent);

    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Use Notification.Builder for new version api