# android: notification doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

hey all i'm making an application where the user's can send gcm messages to each other 
the application is working very good and when i send a gcm message the receiver get it as a notification
and when the receiver click it it opens the homepage.class but the problem is that 
when he click on the notification the Broadcast receiver does not receive it and doesn't make change's to the EditText, On the other hand if the receiver was using homepage.class when the message was received it make change's to the EditText (Working)
what could be the problem ??? 
some methods from my GCMIntentService

```
 @Override
  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomePage.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        // notifies user
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        generateNotification(context, message);

    }

 void displayMessageOnScreen(Context context, String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.ms.gp.wefamily.DISPLAY_MESSAGE");
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        // Send Broadcast to Broadcast receiver with message
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);   
    }
```

and this is the code of my BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override 
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        // Display message on the screen
        Familyname.setText(newMessage);                  
    }
};
```

please if anyone knows the answer tell me (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: the question is unclear to me, why should broadcastreceiver be triggered by clicking the notification???

Comment: also, you have a class called Familiyname??? or is it supposed to be a field...

Comment: Familyname is a EditText Object 
and if the broadcastreceiver is not triggered to the notification 
what should be ?

Comment: broadcast receiver is triggered when receiving a message from GCM, the onclick part goes like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155804/perform-an-action-clicking-notifications-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you register the receiver on its parent activity. Once it's properly registered have it handle the received bundle. Pay attention to the sent value tags.